# Divi builder background video to be muted

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I actually have a site built with divi builder, and I have integrated the background video, can anyone help as where to locate the file in divi builder and mute the video, as of now it is playing along with the sound.

Comment: Why not save the wasted bandwidth and remove the sound from the video entirely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this jQuery solution to mute the background video.
Add this bellow code into *theme option > integration > code integration > Add code to the < head > of your blog*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".et_pb_section_video_bg video").prop('muted', true); 
});
</script>
```

Then let me know the result.

Comment: New Chrome update blocked our background videos, even those without sound. This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this jQuery code to mute the video:

Also, add the CSS class "mutedvideo" on the video module.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".mutedvideo").prop('muted', true); 
 });
 </script>
```

Hope it works.